# csvautotabular with macro code headers

Tags: csv, csvsimple

The [manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) states that macro code is allowed and will be processed accordingly using csvautotabular (section 4.3, page 31).

The header allows some math mode macros such as underlines (X_{1}) and circumflex ($X^{2}). This works fine and is processed correctly.

However, backslashes seems to make csvsimple go crazy. When using the following code snippet:

```
\begin{center}
  \csvautotabular{ass2-1-2.csv}
\end{center}
```

With the following csv file:

```
S,R,Q,$\overline{Q}$
0,1,0,1
0,0,0,1
```

I get the following output;

```
    ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \protect 
l.115 \csvautotabular{ass2-1-2.csv}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.115 \csvautotabular{ass2-1-2.csv}

! Extra \endcsname.
\pgfkeyslet ...ter \let \csname pgfk@#1\endcsname 
                                              #2
l.115 \csvautotabular{ass2-1-2.csv}

)
Runaway argument?
\edef \csv@temp {\noexpand \pgfkeysdef {/csv head/\thecsvcol }{\the \toks \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@temp.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
<*> \nonstopmode\input report.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> \nonstopmode\input report.tex
```

When using macros in data-rows, everything works fine. It is only the header that is complaining. For example, if I change the header in the csv to the following everything works fine:

```
S,R,Q,$Q_{not}$
```

Am I going to have to resort to the cumbersome \csvreader instead? Is this a bug or am I not supposed to be doing stupid things to my header?

Comment: Please show us the code that results in the shown errors ...

Comment: Without an example, it is quite impossible to help. But, generally, the header is not allowed to contain macros. Also, the backslash is not allowed as first character of a data line.